# how to get list from 1 to 10 and from 11 to 20 values (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = 'Andrew' ORDER BY age DESC
```

Here I have some call . For example I have db in which I have 3 columns :

```
user_name, age , id
```

In this db we have 30 the same names ('Andrew') . I want to make order by age as u see above and get list from 1 to 10 , then from 11 to 20 ,then from 21 to 30 .How to make it ?

```
/get-users/:from/:to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, e.g. to get records 11-20 you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_name = 'Andrew'
ORDER BY age DESC
OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: from 0 to 10 I should make smth like this OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10 ?

Comment: You actually don't need `OFFSET` for the first 10.  Just `LIMIT 10` with the desired `ORDER BY` clause should work.

Comment: I can't because I do not have permission for this .. ( very low rate